# Existence of a locally finite refinement with a special continence property

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I was reading a proof involving a manifold $M$ and an open covering $\mathcal U$ of $M$ by the domains of charts in a given atlas. The author then claims that since manifolds are (in his definition) paracompact, one can find a locally finite refinement $\mathcal V$ of $\mathcal U$ such that for every $V \in \mathcal V$ there is $U \in \mathcal U$ satisfying

$$\bigcup \{W \in \mathcal V; V\cap W \neq \emptyset \} \subset U.$$

How can one see this using paracompactness? I've unsuccessfully attempt to construct one such refinement but I don't know much about paracompactness beyond the definition so there might be something I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of refinement is called a [star-refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_refinement). We denote $\cup\{W \in \mathcal{V}: V \cap W \neq \emptyset\}$ by $\operatorname{st}(V,\mathcal{V})$, the star of $V$ in $\mathcal{V}$. A cover $\mathcal{V}$ is called a star-refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ iff for each $V \in \mathcal{V}$, there is some $U \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\operatorname{st}(V,\mathcal{V}) \subset U$, which is exactly your requirement.

Now theorem 2. in [my note here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/02.pdf) says, among other things (and it's in Engelking (chapter 5 paragraph 1) and other textbooks as well, e.g. Willard 20.9), that "$X$ is paracompact" is equivalent to "every open cover has an open star-refinement." (for regular spaces, but paracompact Hausdorff manifolds are regular)
(and we can then ensure it's a locally finite refinement, if we just refine it once more, if necessary).